# How to extract only highlight data from pdf file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to take out all the highlighted text from a pdf in rails does anyone have any idea I am not able to figure it out.[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/au4fz.png)

Comment: Is the text somehow highlighted in the PDF document (like with another font or a background color) or are the users highlighting text segments in their browsers on themselves?

Comment: The highlighted text is marked with yellow colour from there I know that it's highlighted @spickermann

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the pdf-reader gem (the example/text.rb example is simple and worked for me): https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader

Or the command-line utility pdftotext.

```
# Extract all text from a single PDF

require 'rubygems'
require 'pdf/reader'

filename = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)) + "/../spec/data/cairo-unicode.pdf"

PDF::Reader.open(filename) do |reader|
  reader.pages.each do |page|
    puts page.text
  end
end
```

This is a basic text extraction using the gem mentioned above. This should get you a nice head start. You can grab all the text from the document then figure out how to grab those specific sections based on the data you receive back.

Comment: Hey, @nolyoi thanks for responding on this I know that we can extract text like this but my problem statement is how can we extract only the highlighted text I have used this one this only provide me all the text but I am not able to figure out which are the highlighted ones. I am adding the link to the algo where I have written the algo and you may able to help me out with that one. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62712684/how-to-extract-the-highlighted-text-from-the-pdf-in-rails]